# Should I update Python modules?

Tags: python

I'm developing a personal program and sometimes I think it would be a good idea to update the Python modules used in the program but I don't want the program to stop working because of updated functions on the updated modules or something like that. So, since when I started making the program (1 year ago), I've never updated the modules and keep all the installers inside one of the folders of the program to be able to install the correct version of each one (with an automatic installer I made to be faster when installing them). Am I doing right or is this a bad idea? I just don't want to have to reprogram many things in my program if the functions, classes,... of the modules are updated. Does this happen or they will always work? Btw, I'm a Python beginner.

Comment: You probably want to look into "virtual environments". In a lot of cases, there aren't breaking changes by upgrading but some libraries really will break your code base if you update, so you can run programs with a version of the library that you know will work.

Comment: But more directly at your question; if the library has a security bug, you really should update. This is rare across all python modules (in the sense that most don't have a security concern to begin with). Beyond that, updating gives you new features and bug fixes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Updating the modules can of course lead to corrupt code in your project. The module may of course have rewritten functions or classes, removed deprecated code, etc. in another version.

One possible approach would be to create a virtual environment for the project, as already proposed by roganjosh. Here is a helpful link: http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/ .

In this virtual environment you can record your modules in the current versions in a requirements file. This is often done and I think it is also a good practice. An additional advantage of this is that by simply changing the version number in the requirements file you can try out whether a newer version crashes your program or not (of course you can certainly also read the module's documentation, "breaking changes" or similar). Another disadvantage is that the project can only be updated at great expense at some point (too many changes at once). You could then successively update one module after the other and see whether project code needs to be changed here and there.

If you just want to run your project and there are no security concerns, then it's probably enough to fix the versions and that's it.

Comment: I'm not sure it makes sense to push up the version in "requirements". `some_version.+` is surely preferable?

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understood your comment, roganjosh. My idea would be at least to transfer the current project of OP with the current modules to a virtual environment and enter the current versions in a requirements file there, which the program can handle. Then he can try what would happen if you change the versions of individual modules here and there and can then decide step by step whether to make the necessary changes or leave the module as it is.

Comment: My comment is more about making the latest working version a _requirement_. If your code works with any version of a library released for the last 5 years, the _requirement_ should be the lowest working version?

Comment: Yes, sure. You're right. But how can he know this? Isn't the simplest solution just to freeze his working versions and then he is fine to achieve what he wants? Your recommendation could then be a second step (trying to adjust the versions to have a 'real' requirements setting).

Comment: Yep, I agree with you. If I placed myself in the position of the OP, I'm not sure that's the take-away message I'd get from the wording of your answer on this point :)

Comment: thanks, I've made it (hopefully) clear now and updated my answer regarding your comments

Comment: Thanks you both for the info. That was what I was afraid of (project corrupted). I guess I'll use the requirements file and put the correct versions there and I'll test all of the other versions of the modules to see the higher versions compatible with the project. I guess I could use that virtual environment. It seems to be some kind of virtual machine with everything I have installed with Python with a copy of my project for me to test with any modules versions I want, right?

Comment: Not really, its more like an extra layer instead of a complete new sandbox system with own operating system. For system independence you can use docker or virtual machines for example, but this is far behind that question. You still have some dependencies to your system with that approach, but it seems ok for your case. The modules will be copied into a special folder in the virtualenv.

Comment: Yes, I think that was what I was trying to say, but I could not explain it well. Thanks for clarifying. I might use it.

Answer (score 4):

You should definitely look into updating your modules if they have known vulnerabilities. A quick Google of tools that might help you with this turned out a couple of interesting hits:

- [OWASP Dependency Check](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Dependency_Check)
- [`safety`](https://pyup.io/safety/)
- [OSS Index](https://ossindex.sonatype.org/)

Typically open source software use [semantic versioning](https://semver.org/) (or semver) to provide some idea on how upgrading to a specific version will affect you. Specifically the guidelines for what "part" of the version to change depends on how [backwards-compatible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backward_compatibility) the change is going to be:

> Given a version number MAJOR.MINOR.PATCH, increment the:
>
> - MAJOR version when you make incompatible API changes,
> - MINOR version when you add functionality in a backwards-compatible manner, and
> - PATCH version when you make backwards-compatible bug fixes.
>
> Additional labels for pre-release and build metadata are available as extensions to the MAJOR.MINOR.PATCH format.

But then again, this will always be left to the discretion of the author of the module so I suggest that you start taking time to write unit tests for your code. This way, you'll quickly be able to see if an upgrade to one of the modules will break your code. [This](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/tests/) should be a good starting point for a list of tools that may help you with writing your tests.

If you do decide to upgrade, make sure that you are following good practices in making sure that you specify the correct versions of your dependencies properly and [colidyre's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50542686/863111) should help you with that.